# Test coverage in Mocha with Blanket doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, blanket.js

I have a Node app I'd like to test, and get coverage report. I followed the [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket/blob/master/docs/getting_started_node.md) but it doesn't seem to work.

**My source, in `src/two.js`:**

```
var two = 1 + 1;
module.exports = two;
```

**My test, in `test/two.js`:**

```
var expect = require('expect');
var two = require('../src/two');

describe('two', function() {
  it('should be 2', function(done) {
    expect(two).toBe(2);
    done();
  });
});
```

**And my `package.json`:**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "cover": "mocha -r blanket -R html-cov > coverage.html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "blanket": "^1.2.1",
    "expect": "^1.13.4",
    "mocha": "^2.3.4"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm run test` everything works as you'd expect. But when I run `npm run cover`, in my `coverage.html` file I get **0% coverage 0 SLOC** and nothing else.

Comment: it appears @self didn't even read the question before downvoting it and auto pasting that comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to run by adding this to `package.json`:

```
...
  "config": {
    "blanket": {
      "pattern": "src",
      "data-cover-never": ["node_modules"]
    }
  },
...
```

Apparently Blanket does **not** default to `src` despite what the guide says (there's an old [open issue](https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket/issues/430) on GitHub).

It also tries to cover all of the paths that match the pattern, not just the `src` dir, so in this case it tried to cover external files as well (`node_modules/has/src/index.js`, which was installed by Expect). I had to add the `data-cover-never` to avoid it.